# Determine dimGrid in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm tiling a 2D Matrix into blocks of fixed size `BLOCK_DIM 16*16`. Then I found that `dimGrid` is (from internet):

```
dim3 dimGrid((NColumns - 1)/16 + 1, (NRows - 1)/16 + 1).
```

Isn't this reversed? Shouldn't it be Nrows first?

Comment: you decide what the size should be

Comment: In a C/C++ matrix : `matrix[y][x]`, because it is stored in row-mayor. If the writer of the code is a mathematician/works with maths, he/she probably has used math notations to specify the dimension names. In Languages such as FORTRAM or MATLAB, the matrices are stored in column-mayor, `matrix[x][y]`. However, it just depends on what you do Iguess, The size of the grids its for the user to make.

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing the code, I would probably write it the way you have shown.

I think of x,y cartesian space this way:

```
Y
^
|
|
+------->X
```

That is, the "X" axis is the "horizontal" axis and the "Y" axis is the vertical axis.  There is no reason it has to be this way  -- it's just a mental model.  But I think it's fairly common.

Now, If the x,y space is used to represent a 2D image, then as I move from right to left (i.e. along the horizontal axis) I am moving from one column to another in the image.  As I move up and down (i.e. along the vertical axis) I am moving from one row to another in the image.

Therefore, with this mental model, the Y coordinate indicates the **row** and the X coordinate indicates the **column** of the image.  The X coordinate will therefore have a maximum (logical) value equal to the number of columns in the image, and the Y coordinate will have a maximum value equal to the number of rows in the image.  For the proposed `dimGrid` variable definition:

```
dim3 dimGrid((NColumns - 1)/16 + 1, (NRows - 1)/16 + 1).
```

since the `x` grid dimension appears first, we see that this "mental model" is consistent with the definition of `dimGrid`.

This sort of usage also would typically mean that for an image-processing algorithm in CUDA, adjacent threads in X would have "naturally"-calculated 2D indices:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
int idy = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
```

or:

```
int col = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
int row = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
```

such that they would have adjacent X values in the image or adjacent "columns".  In C-style row-major storage, having adjacent threads in X (in the grid) access adjacent columns in the image is usually a good recipe for achieving coalesced access in your kernel.